# Why is the Multilingual App Toolkit not generating machine translations?

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2017, machine-translation, multilingual-app-toolkit

My Multilingual App Toolkit is throwing an error when trying to connect to my azure subscription and generate machine translations.

A couple months ago I successfully set up the new Multilingual App Toolkit to use the Translator Text API in the Azure Market Place on my Azure account.  I did this following the steps on this knowledgebase article:
https://cognitive.uservoice.com/knowledgebase/articles/1128340-announcements-action-required-before-april-30-20

In the last month I used the service and updated my translations.  I can confirm the service used to work and that my Azure account and translation service are both active and no changes were made to any keys.

Error:
[image]

Comment: has anyone been using the toolkit to generate machine translations through the azure webservice recently?

Comment: This is mysteriously been fixed though nothing I've done.  After this error went away I did find that I had to reset the password on my Translation Service Windows Credentials on my host machine.  I did this by simply copy and pasting the translation service key from azure portal into the password.

Comment: I don't use the Azure stuff anymore. I open up translate.bing.com and translate.google.com and translate values in there and lots of copy/paste work. Don't want to suddenly receive an invoice from Azure because I clicked translate all or so...